# Verify Cyanogenmod update - checksum?

Tags: cyanogenmod, updates

I am running Cyanogenmod 11. The OS made an automatic check for updates, and there are new nightly builds available. I downloaded one of them, but have not yet installed it.

Can anyone advise what security features are built into this automatic update process?

- Where is the update downloaded from?
- Is it possible to see the checksum of the update in question?
- Are updates signed?

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to worry about corruption of update. If its corrupt, the zip file will not be parsed and recovery wont flash it, no damage done.

Still, if you want checksums, you can go to http://download.cyanogenmod.com/, find your device and check the checksum of latest build for your device.

If you are still not comfortable installing update, **backup first using recovery**. You can always restore if it doesn't work out.

> Are updates signed?

I dont get what you meant by that. CM updates are signed with Android's default debugging keys (test-keys). Ofcourse feel free to research about this on your own at [Cyanogenmod Wiki](https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org).

Comment: This wasn't exactly what I was looking for, but I did manage to run a checksum of the downloaded file (it's in the cmupdater directory). That matches with the checksum at https://download.cyanogenmod.com/

Comment: Did you guys mean https://download.cyanogenmod.org/ because the .com link is  a 404. Also, these pages on the cyanogenmod site give a 503 error saying they're "over quota" so you can't even get the sha1 hash directly from them, but you can load the google cache version of the site.